# fatal: Authentication failed Git Bash

Tags: git, bash

I've been asked to set up git on my Windows machine in order to work on a project, it is my first time using the software and I have been given limited information other than the clone command below. I am trying the following command:

```
git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/url/project
```

I am prompted to type in my password (which is correct I've even logged in and out of the website to confirm). Then I receive the error:

```
fatal: Authentication for https:://username@bitbucket.org/url/project
```

Am I missing a step here or could there be a permissions error on the other end that I will have to contact the owner for? To clarify I am running msysgit 1.8.4 on Windows 7.

Comment: I had the same problem with bitbucket and didn't have too much time to investigate so I ended up using ssh and public key authentication

Comment: have you added the public key into your bitbucket account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the project is private and you are not on the contributor/team list. You should contact the owner.

Comment: I believe that it is supposed to be private yes, I have contacted the owner to see if I can get added, will report back if it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

If you found authentication error problem when you entered correct password and username it's git problem. To solves this problem when you are installing the git in your machine uncheck the enable git credential manager[image]